# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

Tags: php, mysqlnd

I am using prepared statements but I'm experiencing this problem:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in ...

I tried it in xampp and get_result(); works perfectly, however I have a dedicated server with cPanel/WHM installed and I get this error.  I have installed     MYSQLND rebooted the system but still the error occurs.

My Code:

```
$sqlzprep = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE table1=? AND table2=? AND table3=? AND table4=? AND table5=?");
                $sqlzprep->bind_param("sssss", $list[0], $list[2], $list[3], $list[4], $list[5]);
                $sqlzprep->execute();
                $numrowz = $sqlzprep->get_result();
                $numrowz = $numrowz->fetch_row();
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: You’re obviously missing the mysqli extension. Install it and activate it in the PHP config.

Comment: Update your PHP version. [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) was added in 5.3.0

Comment: @lxg  I think if OP didn't have the *mysqli* extension, it would have bailed on `prepare()` or even earlier at `mysqli_connect()` / `new mysqli` (or however OP is creating their connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enabled mysql, mysqli, and pdo compatibility by creating

```
/var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5
```

In this file place the following directives:

```
--with-mysql=mysqlnd
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
```

and use EasyApache to rebuild your php configurations.

more info here
http://olaitanmayowa.com/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli_stmtget_result/

Comment: OP already has the *mysqli* extension enabled. They also pointed out that they have the mysqlnd extension

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem in the past, even after installing the mysqli extension,